# is there a word which conveys the idea of criticizing with (or out of) love?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word, for criticizing someone out of love. Like a lover would do or a father would do.

It's not just criticising or reproaching, there is that love and care factor involved, for the criticised own good.

Comment: I suggest an adverb+verb construction:  _gently_ chide, _lovingly_ correct, _kindly_ chastise, or such.

Comment: You might "chide" (them) with sarcasm, humor, or seriousness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Tough love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tough_love)**

> Tough love is an expression used when someone treats another person harshly or sternly **with the intent to help them in the long run**. (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 1):

While there are tons of synonyms for *criticise*, I'd go with:

**Chide**

[Free Dictionary](http://thefreedictionary.com/chide)

- To scold mildly so as to correct or improve; reprimand

Answer (score 0):

You have to be cruel to be kind.

Something that you say when you do something to someone that will upset them now because you think it will help them in the future I told her she's just not good enough to be a professional dancer - sometimes you have to be cruel to be kind.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/You+have+to+be+cruel+to+be+kind